# JBOSS 7 AS standalone.sh unable to access jboss-modules.jar

Tags: linux, jboss, centos, jboss7.x, centos6

I'm a bit at wit's end here trying to figure out what's going on. I'm trying to setup JBOSS 7 on CentOS 6 and I keep getting:

```
  =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/share/jboss-7.0.2.Final

  JAVA: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_29/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

Unable to access jarfile /usr/share/jboss-7.0.2.Final/jboss-modules.jar
```

For those wondering, I have a jboss user who owns the entire jboss 7 directory and all files contained within. All the environment variables are set correctly, confirmed by echo and the output above, there are no spaces in JBOSS_HOME nor are there any spaces in standalone.sh. I'd be appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction on this. If I run the server with sudo (bad, I know, just hypothesis testing) it runs. When I run it as the owning user, it dies. I think it's a permissions problem, but I don't know which one to flip as I've flipped all the relevant ones--I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a typo in my JBOSS_HOME variable of all places and forgot to include the -as in the directory name for the JBOSS_HOME variable. Hence, the script was looking for something that didn't exist.